# Auto stopping windows media player when headphone is unplugged

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, media-player, headphones

Is a way to configure windows or at least the windows media player to auto stop playing when the headphone is unplugged from the jack ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your headphone jack is onboard your computer, and not onboard some external speakers. So my answer reflects that. If the jack is on the speakers, then there's definitely no way to do it. Anyways...

WMP isn't designed to do what you want, but here's something you can try: 
 1. make sure WMP is closed. 
 2. set your headphone output to the default playback device in control panel/sound options 
 3. Open WMP and start playing a song. 
 4. Unplug em, and see if it automatically switches to the next audio device, or maybe it will just stop, and say the playback device isn't found.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understand well. Let's suppose we are talking about a laptop with a unique sound card but with two outputs (speakers and headphone). Is your instruction applicable to this kind of laptop ?

Comment: Possibly,
The output for the speakers, and headphones are probably share a device, but will be different from the internal speakers. You should see them as separate devices in sound options. Feel free to take a screen shot of your output/playback tab in sound options and I'll see if I can specify which one to use.

Comment: I cannot see two separeted outputs [link](http://goo.gl/E6LPf), although there is a property that informs the spec for the jack output [link](http://goo.gl/WHwT8). Thanks by the help.

Comment: That being the case my little idea wont work. And because the feature you want isn't built into WMP. The short answer to your initial question is no. Sorry.

Comment: Do you know if others players can do that ? Does Windows provide API to program that ?

Comment: I read a few things while looking for an answer for you that lead me to believe some other media players may have this feature, so it'd be worth hunting if you're open to another media player. On the API question, I don't know. That actually might be worth posting as a new question if you are up to actually code it.